# LINQ Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, sql, linq

Have the following Stored procedure for a search form. I use Linq and have problem to get the result of this procedure....am I in the wrong way in procedure or in linq?

You can see my linq down here too..I have tried different ways..but now i need your help :)

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SearchPostit]
 (
 @message varchar(1000)='', 
 @writer varchar(50)='',
 @mailto varchar(100)='',
 @date varchar(50)=''
 )
AS
 SELECT P.Message AS Postit, P.Mailto AS 'Mailad till', P.[Date] AS Datum, U.UserName AS Användare  
 FROM PostIt P 

 LEFT OUTER JOIN [User] U ON P.UserId=U.UserId

    WHERE P.message LIKE '%'+@message+'%' AND  U.UserName LIKE '%'+@writer+'%' AND P.Mailto LIKE '%'+@mailto+'%' 
    AND P.Date LIKE '%'+@date+'%' 
    GROUP BY P.Message, U.UserName, P.Mailto, P.[Date]



System.ComponentModel.DataObjectMethodAttribute(System.ComponentModel.DataObjectMethodType.Select, true)]
        public DataSet SearchPostit(string message, string writer, string mailto, string date)
        {
            var dc = new LinqClassesDataContext();

            List<SearchPostitResult> p = dc.SearchPostit(message, writer, mailto, date).ToList();

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            dt.Columns.Add("Message", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("UserName",typeof (string));
            dt.Columns.Add("E-mail", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Date",typeof(DateTime));

            foreach(SearchPostitResult res in dc.SearchPostit(message, writer, mailto, date))
            {
                DataRow row = dt.NewRow();

                row["Message"] = res.Postit;
                row["UserName"] = res.User;
                row["E-mail"] = res.Mailto;
                row["Date"]=res.Date;

                dt.Rows.Add(row);
            }
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                ds.Tables.Add(dt);
                return ds;
            }

        }
```

Comment: It would help if you explained what problem you are having.

Comment: what are you using your variable P for?  You've assigned it and then you're not using it in your foreach loop?

Comment: It feels like you're swimming upstream, trying to fight LINQ rather than let it help you.  Why are you manually creating a DataTable instead of just using the List<SearchPostItResult> that LINQ returns?

Comment: Variable p I don´t use, i know...I were just trying thar one to get result...but the result is always Null even when aI know there is a match. My problems are that I don´t know how to get the result from the procedure in linq query....

Comment: Jason: How would you solve it without datatable when I need the return to be dataset?

Comment: If you need to return a DataSet I don't think I would bother with LINQ at all.  I would just use straight ADO.NET calls.  Have you tested your sproc from query analyzer to be sure it works?  The way you're using LIKE for date comparison doesn't seem right, but SQL may be able to parse it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing much about the error, the only thing I can guess (and this is a total guess) is that it looks like the PostIt.Date field in the database isn't a DateTime, and you're trying to put it into a DateTime field in a DataTable. I'm not sure that works.

As a side point, why would you need the overhead of creating a datatable anyway? What's wrong with the collection Linq to Sql is giving back to you?

Comment: I have to return a dataset cause of a interface...can i solve it in other way?